# Examples of pay-what-you want using Bitcoin?

Tags: donation

**Are there any examples of [pay-what-you-want](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_what_you_want) using Bitcoin?**

I could envisage this being done with Bitcoin where the products are toys, postcards, etc., homemade or otherwise, or of course digital products. You could call it a kind of shareware using Bitcoin, or PWYW with Bitcoin, or even value-for-value using Bitcoin, although I am only interested in the case where the minimum amount of Bitcoin payble would be zero Bitcoins.

My question is whether this has actually been tried yet using Bitcoin and, if so, then where and when?

Comment: Is this question really about bitcoin? You could ask the same question without mentioning a specific payment method and it would remain basically the same question.

Comment: It's about Bitcoin, yes, but it could certainly also be asked of other cryptocurrencies or of cryptocurrency in general.

Comment: The term you are looking for is “donationware” or “[pay what you want](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_what_you_want)”.—I'm going to vote to close this question as I agree with Vojtěch, I do not see how this is about Bitcoin. If you disagree, please edit to clarify how your question relates to Bitcoin and vote to reopen.

Comment: Edited. How can I vote to reopen?

Comment: On another site, I see this on one of my closed questions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1F5N.png, but I realize now that it takes 500 reputation to get that option. However, when you edit a question within five days of it having been closed, it automatically gets added to a review queue where people can vote to reopen. In this case, I just voted to reopen for you.

Comment: Can you clarify why it is inadequate to publish a Bitcoin address on a web page, email, dm, tweet, with a message suggesting people pay whatever amount they want?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - I don't know whether that's inadequate or not. The question isn't about hypotheticals. If what you say has ever been done, it could be referenced in an answer. Perhaps someone has tried this as a more extensive practice than a one-off. I haven't found any examples at all. This is is why I asked the question. Gas fees may be a disincentive, but then again perhaps the model has been used for certain types of item and with a guide price at a certain level for those who do wish to pay something. I really don't know. It would be a different model from "buy me a coffee".